# How can I get a path from caller

Tags: php

This is just example to explain.

```
[./includes/functions.inc.php]
function getPHPResult($path) {
    ob_start();
    include $path;
    $result = ob_get_clean();

    return $result;
}

[./pages/a.php]
echo getPHPResult('b.php');

[./pages/b.php]
some php code.
```

This code doesn't work.
Because `'b.php'` in a.php is not valid path in `'getPHPResult'`.

If I use `include 'b.php'` in a.php, b.php in same directory with a.php will be load.
But, if I use `getPHPResult ('b.php')` in a.php, b.php in same directory with functions.inc.php will be load.
But I want to load b.php in same directory with a.php

So, I should change `getPHPResult('b.php')` to `getPHPResult('../includes/b.php')`.
But, It will doesn't work if `a.php` and `b.php` are moved to other directory.

Then, I want to find a correct path in `getPHPResult` function.
My solution is just use `debug_backtrace`.

```
function getPHPResult($path) {
    $backtrace = debug_backtrace(DEBUG_BACKTRACE_PROVIDE_OBJECT, 2);
    $dir = dirname($backtrace[1]['file']);

    ob_start();
    include $dir . '/' . $path;
    return ob_get_clean();
}
```

But, I think it isn't good way.
How can I find a correct path without `debug_backtrace`?

Comment: @Ryan Vincent I'm just trying to make a template engine. The code of the top is just example to explain.

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand what are you mean. But if you want to get filename of a currently executing php script use this,

```
echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
```

Comment: Sorry for my bad English.

Comment: I want to get a relative path from caller file in function.  If I use `include 'b.php'` in a.php then b.php is located at same directory with a.php. but if call `getPHPResult('b.php')` then b.php must be located at same directory with functions.inc.php.  but I want to load b.php in same directory with a.php, so how can I make it?

Comment: then use this and have a look `echo $_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME'];`

Comment: The php file that contains "include 'b.php';" maybe not a SCRIPT_FILENAME.

Comment: if the file which contains "include 'b.php'" is `a.php` and it was loaded in index.php.  then SCRIPT_FILENAME will be 'index.php' but I need 'a.php'

Answer (score 0):

If the location of the scripts is likely to change, then maybe you should try to use absolute paths instead of relative paths. In PHP, there are some predefined ["magic constants"](http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php) that can help you with that.

> __FILE__  The full path and filename of the file with symlinks resolved. If used inside an include, the name of the included file is returned.

The constant `__FILE__` will always return the full path and filename of the script. Maybe you can use that as a starting point.

Comment: but, the caller file may doesn't same to \_\_FILE\_\_.
when... index.php include a.php

Answer (score 0):

If a.php and b.php will be in the same directory, you can safely use the following:

[a.php]

```
echo getPHPResult(__DIR__ . '/b.php');
```

Comment: Thank you for answer. but the way to calculate path in function isn't exist?